# Copying a file to my htdocs on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

Am trying to move a folder from my desktop to to the following directory on ubuntu

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs
```

please help me out i don't have a clue about this.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal go "cp ~/Desktop/htdocs /opt/lampp/htdocs"

You may need elevated priviledges, so you might need to go "sudo !!" after that and put in a password.

Comment: it keeps saying omitting  home/user/Desktop/htdocs

Comment: Sorry, try this:
cp -R ~/Desktop/htdocs* /opt/lampp/htdocs

Answer (score 0):

Please open up a terminal and enter the following command

sudo cp -rv ~/Desktop/foldername /opt/lampp/htdocs

please replace the foldername accordingly and recheck the paths

Answer (score 0):

fell into the same error so what it requires to fix this is give permission to the httdocs folder which you can do by :
NOTE: "user" is you .you can view this by running First \

`whoami`

on terminal then replace user with your own name using code below

`sudo chown user:user /opt/lampp/htdocs`
`sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs`

Comment: this was meant for linux users btw

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal, type */usr/bin/find $HOME/Desktop/htdocs -print |  xargs -J % -n 25 sudo cp % /opt/lampp/htdocs*

Comment: Emm... why the downvote?